# Is there a Möbius transformation mapping an arbitrary disk to the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, mobius-transformation, linear-fractional-transformation

I have the following problem. I'm interested in finding a Möbius transformation mapping an arbitrary disk with radius $R$ centered at $z_0$ to $\Bbb{D}$. I thought that it will be something of the form $$T_w(z)=\frac{z-w}{1-w^cz}$$ where $w^c$ is the complex conjugate of $w$.

Now my idea was to replace $w$ with $z_0$ but then I don't think that this works? does it?

**Edit** I want this for the following reason:

> We assume $f$ to be analytic such that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for $z\in >\Bbb{D}$. Now from the lecture we have the following statement
>
> > Let $g$ he an analytic function satisfies $|g(z)|\leq M$ for $|z->z_0|<R$ then if $g$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$ then >$$|g(z)|\leq \frac{M}{R^m}|z-z_0|^m$$ when $|z-z_0|<R$
>
> Using this we need to show that if $f$ has zero of order $m$ at >$z_0\in \Bbb{D}$ then $$|f(0)|\leq |z_0|^m$$
>
> They told us to use a möbiustransformation as above. My Idea was to >transport the $\Bbb{D}$ to the other cirlce $|z-z_0|<R$ becuase then >we can use our statement. But maybe thats completly wrong.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try the Möbius transformation of the form $z \mapsto az+b$; that is, taking $c=0,d=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate the center of your disk to the origin, and then divide by $R$. The composition of these two transformations is what you want.

Comment: but then is it of this form I wrote above? Because then I think I got something wrong

Comment: No, this is equal to $(z-z_0)/R$

Comment: but $R\neq 1-z_0^c\cdot z$? Because then maybe I missunderstood the exerciese, they told us that we need a $T$ in the form of above

Comment: I don't think so, because $R$ is a constant and the other thing depends on $z$

Comment: @Wave If you compose the map I told with an automorphism of the unit disk, you may get an answer with that form

Comment: so can I maybe ask the question here in a new post and you take a look at it then you maybe see why I try to transform it into the unit disk

Comment: Sure, if you edit the question telling more about context and what you need and why, I may be able to help

Comment: Perfect so I will do it

Comment: I edited it, hopefully you can help me

Comment: Oh, I see. You didn't need to transform one disk into the other, you need an automorphism of the disk (of the form you wrote on the question) which maps $z_0$ to $0$ (that automorphism is exactly what you wrote, with w = z_0). Then the composition with f will have a zero in the center of the disk, I think.

Comment: Sorry could you maybe explain why I don't need to transform one into the other? I don't see why an automorphism is enough?

Comment: I think I don't understand it enough either, sorry

Comment: ah okey perfect thanks! but so I only need to replace $w$ with $z_0$ and I'm done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need to do exactly